# What's the meaning of "rl_actions" of flow/tutorials/tutorial09_environments.ipynb

Tags: sumo, flow-project

When I am learning tutorial 9, I am confusing the rl_actions.
Because on the program, the rl_actions is not initialized and definition.
Why there is a 'rl_actions' parameter of the _apply_rl_actions function and compute_reward function?
I also check the vehicle kernel code, about apply_acceleration function.
The original one is:

```
def apply_acceleration(self, veh_ids, acc):
        """See parent class."""
        # to hand the case of a single vehicle
        if type(veh_ids) == str:
            veh_ids = [veh_ids]
            acc = [acc]

        for i, vid in enumerate(veh_ids):
            if acc[i] is not None and vid in self.get_ids():
                this_vel = self.get_speed(vid)
                next_vel = max([this_vel + acc[i] * self.sim_step, 0])
                self.kernel_api.vehicle.slowDown(vid, next_vel, 1e-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into `flow/envs/base_env.py` in the `step` method, this is where `apply_rl_actions` and `compute_reward` are called. All these 3 methods take as parameter the actions `rl_actions` to apply to the agents. These actions are provided by the RL algorithm. The shape of `rl_actions` is the one provided in the `action_space` method of your environment.

The RL algorithm automatically calls your `step` method at each step, giving it the actions to be applied. Flow's environments are actually encapsulated within a `Gym` environment, which is given to the RL algorithm. The RL algorithm can work with any `Gym` environment, which allows it to be very general, since all `Gym` environments have methods such as `step`, `reset` etc. If you want to know more about how this work, look into how to train a custom `Gym` environment.

Comment: How to look into how to train a custom Gym environment